# Polynomial ring, prime ideal, factor ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to prove that this ideal: $I=(y^3-xz, xy^2-z^2, x^2-yz)$ is prime in $K[x,y,z]$. I think it would be a good idea to prove that the factor ring $K[x,y,z]/I$ has no zero divisors.

In this factor ring the following relations would be satisfied:

$y^3 = xz$

$xy^2=z^2$

$x^2=yz$

So, for example $y^4=x^3$ and $y^5=z^3$

Does that in some way help me prove that the factor ring is an integral domain?

Could you help me a bit?

Comment: Maybe you can observe a homomorphism $\phi:K[x,y,z]\longrightarrow K[t]$ given by: $x\mapsto t^4$, $y\mapsto t^3$, $z\mapsto t^5$. Then $I\leq\ker(\phi)$. Try to prove that equality holds.

Comment: From the equations above, we also have $y^4=x^3$ and $z^4=x^5$. However, I do not see how that implies that $I \subset ker \phi$. Could you tell me why that inclusion holds?

Comment: Look at the image of the generators of $I$ under the map $\phi.$ All the generators map to zero.

Comment: Of course, I see that now. I'll think about the opposite inclusion.

Comment: What does $ker \phi$ look like? $\phi (P(x,y,z)) = P(t^4, t^3, t^5) = 0$. It's hard to infer what relation had to be between $x,y,z$ in order for the polynomial to be zero under the map $\phi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polynomials in $K[x,y,z]$ are linear combinations over $K$ of $\{x^ay^bz^c\mid a,b,c\geq 0\}$. Prove that, modulo $I$, every polynomial in $K[x,y,z]$ are linear combinations over $K$ of $\{y^a,xy^a,zy^a\mid a\geq 0\}$. (This can be done, it is tricky to write. Start with say $x^ay^b$, then decrease its $x$-degree by $x^2=yz$; after maybe $xz=y^3$, you will get term $y^cz^d$, where $d<a$. So, now use $z^2=xy^2$ and ... Consider other cases in a similar way.)

$\phi$ maps the set $\{y^a,xy^a,zy^a\mid a\geq 0\}$ to $\{t^{3a},t^{3a+4},t^{3a+5}\mid a\geq 0\}$, which is linearly independent over $K$. Therefore, for every linear combination $q$ of $\{y^a,xy^a,zy^a\mid a\geq 0\}$ over $K$, if $\phi(q)=0$, then $q=0$.

Now, take $p(x,y,z)\in\ker(\phi)$; write $p(x,y,z)$ modulo $I$ as a linear combination $q$ of $\{y^a,xy^a,zy^a\mid a\geq 0\}$ over $K$. Since $p=q\mod I$, then $\phi(q)=0$, hence $q=0$, and therefore $p\in I$.

Comment: I thought about doing the tricky part like this: $x^ay^bz^c = (xz)^cx^{a-c}y^b = y^{3c+b}x^{a-c}$. Now $x^3=y^4$, so I consider $3$ possible residues of $a-c$ modulo $3$. I get $y^{3c+b}x^{a-c} = y^{3c+b}x^{3n+1} = y^{3c+b+4n}x$ if $a-c \ \equiv 1$ mod $3$, for example. Is this approach all right?

Comment: Yes, that works!

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I just have one more question. The map $\phi$ isn't surjective, is it?

Comment: No. But $K[x,y,z]/I\leq K[t]$ is integral domain anyway.

Comment: Well, $\mathrm{im}(\phi)= K+t^3K[t]$.

Comment: In fact, the image of $\phi$ is the $K$-subalgebra (of $K[t]$) $K[t^3,t^4,t^5]$.

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: So how to prove that it is an integral domain?

Comment: If we take $(a+t^3P(t))(b+t^3Q(t)) = ab + at^3Q(t) + bt^3P+t^6Q(t)P(t) = 0$, how to prove that one of $a+t^3P(t), \ \ b+t^3Q(t)$ is zero?

Comment: Subring of an integral domain is integral domain. (If you have no zero divisors in greater ring, then you can't have them in smaller ring.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Stupid of me. Thanks.